# What does import attr mean in Python?

Tags: python

In Python code, I foudnd this line. What does it mean?

```
import attr
```

Here is an example:

```
import collections

import attr
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: Most probably:  [Simple decorator to set attributes of target function or class in a DRY way.](https://github.com/denis-ryzhkov/attr)

Answer (score 7):

attrs is the Python package that gives you a class decorator and a way to declaratively define the attributes on that class:. An example is given below:-

```
import attr 
@attr.s
class SomeClass(object):
  a_number = attr.ib(default=42)    
  list_of_numbers = attr.ib(factory=list) 
  def hard_math(self, another_number):   
     return self.a_number 
     +sum(self.list_of_numbers) * 
     another_number
```

For a detailed explanation visit https://pypi.org/project/attrs/.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is using attr package 
Check https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html